# Derivable sequent

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, proof-theory, sequent-calculus

I’m currently following the book “Mathematical logic” of Ebbinghaus. He says that a **sequent** $\Gamma\varphi$ is **derivable** when exists a derivation of this sequent in the sequent calculus $\mathfrak{S}$ and we note it as $\vdash\Gamma\varphi$ or even $\Gamma\vdash\varphi$. I understood this as “from $\Gamma\varphi$ you can get another sequent using the rules of the calculus” but probably I’m not understanding well the motivation of this definition because is difficult for me to imagine a sequent that would be not derivable by means of some of the rules, specially some like Antecedent rule or Assumption rule. Could someone bring me a sequent that is not derivable in this sense?.

In fact, the definition fits better for me if I think about the derivability of $\ \Gamma\varphi$ as “from another sequents you can reach $\Gamma\varphi$ using the rules of the calculus” instead as I said before.

Comment: The calculus is *sound* and thus he will not produce sequents that are contradictions, like $\vdash \varphi \land \lnot \varphi$.

Comment: Assumption rule does not say that a sequent whatever is derivable; it says that the sequent $\Gamma \ \varphi$ is **when** $\varphi \in \Gamma$. In the presence of the Antecedent rule it amounts to $\varphi \vdash \varphi$.